# Omnicontacts gem: Outlook invalid_request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, outlook, omnicontacts-gem

Ruby gem works great for us for Gmail and Yahoo. When accessing via Outlook and their new API we are getting the error below.

NOTE: This happens after we successfully receive the params[:code] and are trying to get the token. Any ideas?

```
{  
   "error":"invalid_request",
   "error_description":"AADSTS90019: No tenant-identifying information found in either the request or implied by any provided credentials.\r\nTrace ID: 791c90ec-0f53-46c8-b15d-a3fe9f07bf18\r\nCorrelation ID: e7e0d207-2c99-4f88-bb6b-2ea62ec19e1d\r\nTimestamp: 2016-05-17 17:07:43Z",
   "error_codes":[  
      90019
   ],
   "timestamp":"2016-05-17 17:07:43Z",
   "trace_id":"791c90ec-0f53-46c8-b15d-a3fe9f07bf18",
   "correlation_id":"e7e0d207-2c99-4f88-bb6b-2ea62ec19e1d"
}
```

Comment: Solution: Need to use an account that is @outlook.com to generate your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Need to use an account that is @outlook.com to generate your credentials.

You can't use a personal or work email address... turns out it must be an actual @outlook.com account.